# relative links being interpreted differently possibly by php

Tags: url, webserver

in the a tags on my site I have them set like so:

```
<a href="/home"></a>
```

This works fine on my test server which is http, however when I push my site to my production server which is https it leads to a "this site can not be reached page". I've found that modifying the a tag by adding a / on the end like this:

```
<a href="/home/"></a>
```

Makes it work. I think that this could be due to the way PHP or the server is interpreting my relative links. Can anyone tell me why these links without the / at the end would work on http and not on https? Also is there some way I can amend this server side without having to go through and add / to the end of all the links?

thanks!

Comment: it is not the TLS, most probably it's something in your `.htaccess` file appending the filenames. Check it out. Also, a website filename without a extension `.php`, `.jpg`, `.html` etc. is going to be assumed as a folder, so the server is looking for a folder unless it's being told otherwise by something such as `mod_rewrite`

Comment: This definitely has _nothing_ to do with php, such a request never even reaches php, exactly _because_ the link is wrong. This is an issue with the link itself and the http server that tries its best to identify the resource you are trying to reference. What path is the correct one is something that depends on your http host configuration and (maybe) your file system layout. Nothing php can do here...

Comment: Thanks for both the responses. @Martin you're saying that this should be able to be resolved with mod_rewrite? Still don't understand why it works on http and not on https

Comment: @arkascha I updated the Q tags

Comment: Ben we'd need to know what sort of platform your server is running on? *Nx, Apache, IIS, etc? Mod_rewrite is Apache specific (as is `htaccess`) so I don't know if it's something you can use.

Comment: Ok, it's an Amazon Linux server. If that's too vague then i can get more details if you tell me what additional details you need

Comment: Sorry just saw in my php info the server api is  Apache 2.0 Handler

Comment: That means you can use `.htaccess` and also research `mod_rewrite` if you want special actions to occur for example if someone opens `site.com/home` and you want it to load a page `site.com/index.php?page=home` , etc. All site builder frameworks (Wordpress, etc) will do this themselves, if you have one installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and auto correct this issue with an edit to `.htaccess` as follows:

```
#declared once at top of htaccess file.
RewriteEngine On    

#if is a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#enforce a trailing slash to the directory given
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

This will work, but I'm not sure the order priority of actions in your server setup; the Amazon system may well be checking if it's a folder before allowing your account `.htaccess` to play with the URI.

But the above will mean:

```
www.yoursite.com/index.php

www.yoursite.com/home
```

will be processed by the server as :

```
www.yoursite.com/index.php

www.yoursite.com/home/ 
 --> and so will load the default index file from this directory, not shown to browser 
  --> www.yoursite.com/home/index.php
```

Comment: Thanks @Martin i'll try this soon and let you know. Will the above also work when there's a redirect? For example I use a few redirects in my php and js files like header("location:/home"); or window.location.href = "/home";

Comment: It will work every time the server is given a page address, so yes. @BenLiger